# MySQL statement search all tables for one specific column?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I am using the command line in MySQL on a Linux box.

I am logged in as root.

I need to find a field that in a table somewhere (in this schema there are 400+ tables)

Field is called 'discounts' or 'discounts'

I just need to find what table that specific field is in and if it is in more then one table with that feild or not.

Thanks for your help guys.

Edit
so the db is called magento and the tables are in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'discount' or LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'discounts';
```

Comment: this works great! but it dumbs everything with the word 'discount' I need only discount or discounts...

Comment: You can use condition like LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'discount' or LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) = 'discounts'

Comment: This works great, but how do i see everything with the word discount in it? (some of the ones have discount_(other text) )?

Comment: SELECT * FROM MAGENTO.COLUMNS WHERE LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE = 'discount';

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'discounts'
```